# PHP: How to select and display a particular date in database?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I stored date in database as dd/mm/yyyy format. So is it possible the month(date) function read as that format?

Here is my code to select & display the information:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM tempahanbilik
                WHERE status != 'BELUM DIPROSES'&& MONTH(tarikh)=4
                ORDER BY tarikh DESC";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error._LINE_);

        $total = $result->num_rows;
        if($total>0)
        {
           while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
           {

            echo"
            <tr>

            <td>{$row['tarikh']}</td>
            <td>{$row['tarikh2']}</td>
            <td>{$row['masa']}</td>
            <td>{$row['tempat']}</td>
            <td>{$row['namaProgram']}</td>
            <td>{$row['tujuan']}</td> 
            <td>{$row['status']}</td>

            </tr>\n";
          }
        }

        else
        {

             echo"


        <tr>

          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td>
          <td>-</td> 
          <td>-</td>




        </tr>\n";

      }
```

But now, my problem is it returns a blank page

Comment: Do not store dates as text

Comment: why arent you selecting the date only from the table?

Comment: You don't display the result

Comment: @Jens i've stored it as varchar. is it possible?

Comment: @HasifahHassan, MONTH is a date function and not for string. (varchar is considered as string.)

Comment: _“i've stored it as varchar”_ - then go fix that first of all. Everything else is really rather nonsense.

Comment: while { } else { } doesn't exist, check your syntax

Comment: as an alternative. you could use `STR_TO_DATE()` function with that and just use `having` on the aggregate, but like what others have said, you should have set the data type as date from the table creation

Comment: OK. Noted with thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MONTH is a date function and not for string. (varchar is considered as string.)

Just use  like `%/04/%`.

Or the complete line is:

```
SELECT * FROM tempahanbilik WHERE status != 'BELUM DIPROSES' && tarikh like '%/04/%' ORDER BY tarikh DESC";
```

NOTE: Order by tarikh will not give you proper result because it will order that column values as string values and so order will be wrong.

Comment: okay i've got the result. Thanks for your help @HimanshuUpadhyay

Comment: your welcome @HasifahHassan, can you accept my answer and vote it up please?

Comment: Someone down voted. Can you please tell me the reason?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure too :(

Comment: Some answers, like this one, make the world a little worse than it was before. That's fine, because there are always lots of other answers that make the world so much better - such as Jens's answer submitted in the comments section below the OP's question.

Comment: @Strawberry, we could ask not to store dates as varchar if he would be asking us for db schema. But OP has already the structure and asking for the help with what he is stuck. So the answer does not deserve to get down voted.

Comment: I think we have a higher responsibility, but you're obviously entitled to disagree.